# Ubuntu 13.04 boots as terminal. No graphics. Radeon HD 7550M

Tags: installation, 13.04, drivers, graphics, radeon

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a pre-installed windows 8 Vaio. The thing is, Ubuntu boots as **terminal, no graphic enviroment**. (In fact, when it boots the screen starts to flash and flicker, though I can hear the login sound. It boots as terminal when I use nomodeset boot option). I think that the problem is the video card: an **Advanced Microdevices Radeon HD 7550M 1GB**. I see there's a driver available at the Radeon website, **but I don't know how to download and install it by terminal**. Also, I'm not sure the problem is actually the driver. Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://www.linuxtechtips.com/2012/12/amd-radeon-hd-7670m-on-ubuntu-1204.html

It's not for the 7550M, but it more or less works good enough to use the graphic enviroment to actually install the proper drivers.